# Running nodejs server in background after ssh timeout (Red Hat machine)

Tags: node.js, ssh

I am trying to run a nodejs server in a background process in a machine which I ssh into.

I use `nohup node app.js &`. However if my ssh connection times out the app also stops running in the background. Is there a way to keep the node server continuously running even after the timeout.

Comment: what if you say `ssh user@server "nohup node app.js &"`?

Comment: @fedorqui whats the difference between what you mentioned and what i do ?

Comment: I have read it in [Run a nohup command over SSH, then disconnect](http://askubuntu.com/a/349275/143251). Now, though, I notice the case is different. Have you tried with [`screen`](http://askubuntu.com/a/8657/143251)?

Comment: So you want to run a node.js server and leave the remote machine without stopping the process, right? Have you tried using pm2?